# Reuse part of a Regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

Consider this (very simplified) example string:

```
1aw2,5cx7
```

As you can see, it is two `digit/letter/letter/digit` values separated by a comma.

Now, I *could* match this with the following:

```
>>> from re import match
>>> match("\d\w\w\d,\d\w\w\d", "1aw2,5cx7")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01749D40>
>>>
```

The problem is though, I have to write `\d\w\w\d` twice.  With small patterns, this isn't so bad but, with more complex Regexes, writing the exact same thing twice makes the end pattern enormous and cumbersome to work with.  It also seems redundant.

I tried using a named capture group:

```
>>> from re import match
>>> match("(?P<id>\d\w\w\d),(?P=id)", "1aw2,5cx7")
>>>
```

But it didn't work because it was looking for two occurrences of `1aw2`, not `digit/letter/letter/digit`.

Is there any way to save part of a pattern, such as `\d\w\w\d`, so it can be used latter on in the same pattern?  In other words, can I reuse a sub-pattern in a pattern?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, when using the standard library `re` module, regular expression *patterns* cannot be 'symbolized'.

You can always do so by re-using Python variables, of course:

```
digit_letter_letter_digit = r'\d\w\w\d'
```

then use string formatting to build the larger pattern:

```
match(r"{0},{0}".format(digit_letter_letter_digit), inputtext)
```

or, using Python 3.6+ f-strings:

```
dlld = r'\d\w\w\d'
match(fr"{dlld},{dlld}", inputtext)
```

I often do use this technique to compose larger, more complex patterns from re-usable sub-patterns.

If you are prepared to install an external library, then the [`regex` project](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) can solve this problem with a [*regex subroutine call*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html). The syntax `(?<digit>)` re-uses the pattern of an already used (implicitly numbered) capturing group:

```
(\d\w\w\d),(?1)
^........^ ^..^
|           \
|             re-use pattern of capturing group 1  
\
  capturing group 1
```

You can do the same with *named* capturing groups, where `(?<groupname>...)` is the named group `groupname`, and `(?&groupname)`, `(?P&groupname)` or `(?P>groupname)` re-use the pattern matched by `groupname` (the latter two forms are alternatives for compatibility with other engines).

And finally, `regex` supports the `(?(DEFINE)...)` block to 'define' subroutine patterns without them actually matching anything at that stage. You can put multiple `(..)` and `(?<name>...)` capturing groups in that construct to then later refer to them in the actual pattern:

```
(?(DEFINE)(?<dlld>\d\w\w\d))(?&dlld),(?&dlld)
          ^...............^ ^......^ ^......^
          |                    \       /          
 creates 'dlld' pattern      uses 'dlld' pattern twice
```

Just to be explicit: the standard library `re` module does not support subroutine patterns.

Comment: @iCodez Is [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21560430/3719101) with named groups instead, like `(?'digitletters'\d\w\w\d),(?&digitletters)` not a way to actually "symbolize patterns" and factorize them within the regex? If yes, maybe you could mark it as accepted instead or people will keep thinking there is no way to do so.

Comment: @iago-lito: The Python `re` module doesn't support recursive patterns. Only `regex` does. Note that you can't ping the OP in a comment on answers they haven't participated in.

Comment: Arh, okay. Thank you for both clarifications :) Maybe it's worth at least notifying readers that PCRE supports it? I came to this post while not specifically searching for a python-flavored regex solution.

Comment: @iago-lito: I don't quite see the point. This question is about Python and it's standard library `re` module, not about regular expression engines in general. There are way too many variations between engines, there is no one standard regular expression syntax. You'd be better off going to a site like https://www.regular-expressions.info/ which specialises in tracking [the various different regex features and what implementations support which ones of those](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refbasic.html).

Answer (score 8):

**Note: this will work with [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), not with `re` module.**

You could use the notation `(?group-number)`, in your case:

```
(\d\w\w\d),(?1)
```

it is equivalent to:

```
(\d\w\w\d),(\d\w\w\d)
```

Be aware that `\w` includes `\d`. The regex will be:

```
(\d[a-zA-Z]{2}\d),(?1)
```

Comment: Too bad :-(  it's a PCRE feature, I thought Python recognize it.

Comment: For named capture groups use `(?&name)`. The alternative forms `(?P>name`) and `(?P&name)` are also supported. `regex` is great!

Comment: Yes! The `regex` module on PyPI is great! This answer is also great! +1

Answer (score 0):

I was troubled with the same problem and wrote [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/urigoren/5a9ab6edcd36752c41f4e20a0eb10be6)

```
import nre
my_regex=nre.from_string('''
a=\d\w\w\d
b={{a}},{{a}}
c=?P<id>{{a}}),(?P=id)
''')
my_regex["b"].match("1aw2,5cx7")
```

For lack of a more descriptive name, I named the partial regexes as `a`,`b` and `c`.

Accessing them is as easy as `{{a}}`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
digit_letter_letter_digit = re.compile("\d\w\w\d") # we compile pattern so that we can reuse it later
all_finds = re.findall(digit_letter_letter_digit, "1aw2,5cx7") # finditer instead of findall
for value in all_finds:
    print(re.match(digit_letter_letter_digit, value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using re, why not use string processing to manage the pattern repetition as well:

```
pattern = "P,P".replace("P",r"\d\w\w\d")

re.match(pattern, "1aw2,5cx7")
```

OR

```
P = r"\d\w\w\d"

re.match(f"{P},{P}", "1aw2,5cx7")
```

Comment: That's rather unreadable. Why not just use string substitutions?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, you are right. In fact using re.sub() didn't actually work as I wrote it because regex special characters were being processed instead of simply replacing the source.

Answer (score -1):

Try using back referencing, i believe it works something like below to match

```
1aw2,5cx7
```

You could use

```
(\d\w\w\d),\1
```

See here for reference http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this won't actually work in my case.  Using `\1` will make it look for two occurrences of `1aw2`.  I want two occurrences of `\d\w\w\d`, regardless of the digits/letters.

Comment: The [`\1` back reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) matches the *literal text* that the numbered group matches. It doesn't re-use the pattern.